# select for update in DB2

Tags: db2

Does DB2 supports select for update similar to MySQL?

Requirement:

Wanted to run select query to retrieve records from table say 'XYZ' & at the same time wanted to update same table to set flag value to true for the selected records only.

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual?

Comment: Sorta - depends on version (you need a table-change-reference).  However, I'm concerned with what you're trying to accomplish - why do you need to do this (what larger problem are you trying to solve)?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to run below query & exporting ONLY 'description' column values to a text file.    Query: select id,description from table where processed=0.   Once exporting to a file is done i wanted to update processed=1 for the only ids selected in the 'select' query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to get some data from before you update, you can use a `SELECT ... FROM OLD TABLE (update-statement)` syntax. Here's an example (this assumes DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, but may work for other platforms).

```sql
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.SELECT_FROM_INSERT_TEST (
     ID INTEGER
    ,STRING VARCHAR(100)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;

INSERT INTO SESSION.SELECT_FROM_INSERT_TEST VALUES
    (1, 'abc'),
    (2, 'def'),
    (3, 'ghi')
;

SELECT ID FROM OLD TABLE (
    UPDATE SESSION.SELECT_FROM_INSERT_TEST
       SET STRING = 'lmnop'
    WHERE ID = 1
)
;
```